# Почему не работает фильтрация в Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Так запускаю фильтер по checkbox
Моторола: `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Motorola" ng-true-value='Motorola' ng-false-value=''> <br />`
Так вывожу товары.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 phone" ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:filter | filter:Dell | filter:Motorola">
    <img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}" alt="{{phone.name}}">
    <h1>{{phone.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    <strong>{{phone.price}} $</strong>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-true-value` и `ng-false-value` ожидают константы. То есть, заменяйте:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Motorola" ng-true-value='Motorola' ng-false-value=''>
```

с

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Motorola" ng-true-value="'Motorola'" ng-false-value="">
```

---

Посмотрите **[этот jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpp8ehgg/1/)**